# How to ensure multi-threads push two values on two lockfree queues respectively (in one atomic operation) without using lock in C++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, lock-free

I am trying to figure out a way to push two values onto two boost::lockfree::queues and preserve the sequence of the pair of values.  Seeking some ideas.

For example, my input values are {apple1, apple2}, {orange1, orange2}, {peach1, peach2}, ... the two queues should look like:

```
Q1: apple1, orange1, peach1, ...
Q2: apple2, orange2, peach2, ...

/// multithreads can execute the following code
lockfree::queue<string*> q1(100), q2(100);
string* val1 = new String("first");
string* val2 = new String("second");

unique_lock<mutex> lk(mtx);
while (!q1.push(val1)); while (!q2.push(val2));
lk.unlock();
// do some more things
```

The reason that I am trying to remove the lock is because my code is reaching deallock because another thread was also using lock.  I have a complicated design that involves more than 10 threads cooperating to finish one task.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be better to choose an ordering for your locks and make sure all threads lock in that order?  Then deadlocks cannot happen.

Comment: Have looked at the code for 2 weeks, playing with lock order seems not possible.  Only using 2 locks.  So if I can remove this lock then I can solve the problem. If could not remove this lock then will try to remove the other lock with is part of a sorted list.

Comment: If you modify the code to only have 1 lock instead of 2 (i.e. replace all instances of locking/unlocking the second mutex with code that locks/unlocks the first mutex instead), your problem will go away (it's impossible to deadlock a program that locks only a single mutex)

Trying to replace the locking with lockless algorithms, OTOH, will probably not work, since it's likely your code does things (e.g. multiple unrelated operations) that cannot be reliably done using only lockless operations.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner you may be correct.  I am still trying to understand my own code. My program execute for a while generating partial result, then blocked at the lock step.  I am just trying to experiment, how about removing this lock.  I might have some idea as to to implementing an alternative.  Multithreading is tough.  Simple code can turn to very complicated many more lines.  I have no choice but to use multithread to reduce the run time. This Patient testing, speed means saving lifes.

Comment: Jeremy You are correct.  I found a solution to use lockfree to write to two queues still stuck, one of the step probably exhausted some resource.  There are quite of few memory pools used to save the time to allocating and deallocating.  This algorithm worked before, the last step I just added multithreading.  So I will have a hard time trying to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I figured out how to replace lock with a loop. In the context of my design, this seemed to have improved performance.

```
atomic<bool> qguard(false);
while (true) {
   bool canpush=false;
   if (qguard.compare_exchange_strong(canpush, true)) {
      while (!q1.push(val1));
      while (!q2.push(val2));
      qguard.store(false);
      break;
   }
}
```

I think this can be further improved by 1. using atomic_flag. 2. using memory_order_acq_rel in the compare_exchange_strong() function and memory_order_release. This solution is lock-free, but not wait-free.

Apparently, this may be a bad solution according to the article: [comparing lock to spin lock](https://matklad.github.io/2020/01/04/mutexes-are-faster-than-spinlocks.html) https://matklad.github.io/2020/01/04/mutexes-are-faster-than-spinlocks.html

Comment: Ok, congratulations, you've invented a spinlock, and implemented it without any of the usual niceties like `_mm_pause()` in a read-only retry loop.  It's not lock-free; a thread can set `qgard` to true (taking the spinlock) and then go to sleep, blocking progress by all other threads indefinitely.  This case is normally handled (in a more full-featured lock) via a fallback to system calls that lets this thread give up the CPU until it's woken by another thread releasing the lock.

Comment: Good comment. It is learning experience to me.  I am running a test on this lock to spin-lock.  The spin lock may not be better than a regular lock, actually doing more work.

Comment: This is way worse than using a lock.